# project that references another project with WCF service reference - default endpoint not found

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf

I have a project called "AppCore" that I am reusing/referencing in several other projects. AppCore had a method for sending mail via system.net that simplifies emailing. However, I created a WCF service reference (to a service that sends mail in a queue) in the AppCore project, created a test form and was able to use the service just fine. When I create a new project (project name "FeedReader") and reference the AppCore project, however, I get an error: "Could not find default endpoint element that references contract" when attempting to access the WCF service. I think this has something to do with the compiler looking for endpoint info in the FeedReader project app.config file and not getting it from the AppCore project app.config file.

If I reference the WCF service directly from the FeedReader project, the endpoint is found. This would be just fine, however I have a dozen or so other projects I wish to have make this same reference and creating a service reference for all of these and future projects makes management difficult and there's no code reuse (something I wish to avoid).

Is this not possible to do (reference a project that references a WCF service)?

In the AppCore project app.config file, you can see the endpoint (it works fine)

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ISendMailService" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://mailservice:9999/SendMailService.svc/SendMailService"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ISendMailService"
        contract="Service_SendMail.ISendMailService" name="BasicHttpBinding_ISendMailService" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Naturally, the other projects don't have endpoints defined as they are referencing AppCore (of which there is a definition). NOTE: I plan on having another few service references in AppCore - but am stuck at just one for now until I can solve this dilemma.

Comment: forgot to mention, the AppCore project is just a class library.

Comment: You can reference a class library that has a WCF reference in it - you just need to make sure that the `<system.serviceModel>` section is in the web/app.config file of the **consuming** application - class libraries don't use their own app.config files.

Comment: ah, okay. I was afraid of that. I'll try making the reference in the code instead of a config file and see if that works. 
I've found in the past that the app.config is compiled into the class library - but, perhaps only the application/user settings are the only things compiled.